# WebPartAdder_ItemCannotBeAddedULS

Tags: web-part

I am unable to add a web part to a publishing page. I am seeing the following in the ULS:

File 0f4c91df-ccde-48e9-9c80-3612e95fa849 has length 889, but corresponds to Features\Components\BannerModule\BannerModule.webpart (version 4; LCID 1033) with length 882

SharePoint Foundation   Web Parts   tkqm   High      WebPartAdder_ItemCannotBeAddedULS

I have four other webparts in the same Feature and all work fine.

Any insights as to why the file sizes would differ?

Answer (score 1):

Had to use Reflector's debugger to determine that a property getter was throwing a null reference exception. Breakpoints on my ctor were never hit...

Also, the object in question was changed from List to Collection at the suggestion of FxCop. The List object was not null.